# How do I create a joined string from fileincludes

Tags: .net, f#, f#-fake

I am using FAKE as a build tool but I must admit I am fairly new to `F#` and functional programming

for running my test I use the following code which works:

```
trace "BuildTests..."
!! "Tests/**.Tests/*.csproj"
|> Seq.iter (fun p -> 
  [p]
  |> MSBuildDebug (testDir @@ Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(p)) "Build"
  |> Log "TestBuild-Output: "
)

trace "RunTests..."
!! (testDir + "**/*.Tests.dll") 
  |> MSTest (fun p -> 
    { p with 
        TestSettingsPath = testSettingsPath
        ResultsDir = artifactsDir
        ErrorLevel = ErrorLevel.DontFailBuild })
```

But now I want to use `OpenCover` instead of MSTest to run  my tests. Basically the call to OpenCover is

```
OpenCover (fun p -> 
    { p with 
        Output=(artifactsDir + "output.xml")
        OptionalArguments = "-excludebyfile:*Designer.* -returntargetcode" })
        "/testcontainer:Path.To.First.Test.dll /testcontainer:Path.To.Second.Test.dll"
```

So my question is how do I convert a FileInclude result like `!! (testDir + "**/*.Tests.dll")`to a combined string

```
/testcontainer:file1.dll /testcontainer:file2.dll /testcontainer:file3.dll
```

so I can use it with the OpenCover Task

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar to your

```
!! "Tests/**.Tests/*.csproj"
|> Seq.iter (fun p ->
```

convert the Seqeuence to an Array and concat it.

```
!! (testDir + "**/*.Tests.dll") 
|> Seq.toArray 
|> String.concat " "
```

Comment: The key thing to notice is that fileincludes implements IEnumerable, so you can use the seq functions on it. Just wanted to bring this to attention.